# limiting results in local DBpedia SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to get instances that contains keywords using `bif:contains`, but I want to get only one label for each `?s` (instance) and I don't care which one. I can't filter it with something like `regex` because it's for a general query. This is my query but it gets all labels from each instance (`?s`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s,?o1,?sc,?l WHERE {
  ?s ?s1textp ?o1 .
  ?o1 bif:contains ' (madrid AND embargo) ' OPTION ( score ?sc ) . 
  ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l      
}
ORDER BY DESC ( ?sc )
LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

I tried out with nested queries, but when I add a `LIMIT` I get no results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s,?o1,?sc,?l WHERE {
  ?s ?s1textp ?o1 .   
  ?o1 bif:contains ' (madrid AND embargo) ' OPTION ( score ?sc ) .                 
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?s,?l WHERE {
      ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l
    }
    LIMIT 1
  }      
}
ORDER BY DESC ( ?sc )
LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

I saw also the [`SAMPLE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggSample) aggregate function; it takes exactly what I want in DBpedia endpoint, but it's not working on my own Virtuoso! (I'm using the open source version.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s,?o1,?sc,?l WHERE {
  ?s ?s1textp ?o1 .
  ?o1 bif:contains ' (madrid AND embargo) ' OPTION ( score ?sc ) . 
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?s,(SAMPLE(?l) AS ?l) WHERE {
      ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?l
    }
    GROUP BY ?s
  }
}
ORDER BY desc ( ?sc )
LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) is running on Virtuoso, so if that's doing the right thing, you probably just need to update your own Virtuoso instance.  VOS is currently at [`7.2.2` (or `6.1.8`, if you must stay on v6)](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews) <strike>`6.1.6`</strike>, and the Virtuoso [Github space](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/) ([instructions](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSGitUsage)) holds the latest code cuts in `stable/7` and `develop/7` (and `stable/6` and `develop/6`), each of which delivers what the path suggests.

For the future -- questions specifically regarding Virtuoso are generally best raised on the [public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).